# Configure Programmatic Deployment for Virtual Machines from an Image

Tags: image, azure, virtual-machine, subscription, portal

I want to create several VM's from [this](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.windows-data-science-vm?tab=Overview) Image automatically.

When I'm getting redirected to the Portals Website I can choose the option "Want to deploy programmatically? Get started-->". Yes, I want to, but in this Windows it seems like my Subscription isn't enabled for this option.
[(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bSws.jpg) So it's just a button to enable my Subscription, isn't it? Otherwise the status was "Enabled" or "Disable" to disable my Subscription. If I click the "Enable"-Button, nothing happens.

Does anyone of you have an idea how to enable my Subscription? Well, perhaps my thinking is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Well, This Enable option is Accepting the Terms of use as blow in advance:**

> By enabling programmatic purchases for the subscriptions selected
> below, I (a) agree to the legal terms and privacy statement(s)
> associated with each offering above, (b) for Azure subscriptions
> purchased from Microsoft, authorize Microsoft to charge or bill my
> current payment method for the fees associated with my use of the
> offering(s), including applicable taxes, with the same billing
> frequency as my Azure subscription, until I discontinue use of the
> offering(s), and (c) agree that Microsoft may share my contact
> information, and transaction details associated with my purchase of
> the above offering(s), with any third-party vendors, if listed above.
> Microsoft does not provide rights for third-party products or
> services. See the [Azure Marketplace Terms](https://azure.microsoft.com/support/legal/marketplace-terms/) for additional terms.

## When you use Azure portal to create Data Science Virtual Machine - Windows 2016:

In the last step, you will agree the Terms of user by clicking "Create":
[image]

## But When you use Powershell or API to create Data Science Virtual Machine - Windows 2016:

It will aslo need to agree this Terms of user by UI, but if you want to approach automation without UI, you need to agree the Terms of user in Advance for your Subscription.

So, you can see the difference between the Enabled and NOT Enabled subscritpion Status of this Marketplace image:

**Enabled:**
[image]

**NOT Enabled**
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I did execute this command and unfortunatelly I agreed the terms already. By the way: My thinking is a bit wrong, because I'll get the option to enable or disable subscriptions, if I have more than one, so finding an issue in that way doesn't solve the problem :(
I'm solving the issue in another way, but it isn't the same topic like this Question so if someone want to hear this solution can write a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I "solve" the Problem: There wasn't any. You can only enable/disable Subscriptions if you have more than one.